# Return from Switch statement inside Array.map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a reducer that gets an array of objects from an action. In these objects, one of their keys is an id. I'm iterating through this array inside the reducer with `Array.map()` and use a `switch` statement where I categorize the objects in arrays in the state based on their ids. The problem is that my switch statement doesn't return anything and it goes to the default case (initial state).

Action creator

```
export const categorizeArrays = arr1 => ({
  type: Types.CATEGORIZE_FAV_ARRAYS,
  arr1
})
```

Reducer

```
export default function favReducer(state = FAV_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case Types.CATEGORIZE_FAV_ARRAYS:

      action.arr1.map(item => {

        switch (item.id) {
          case 28:
            return {
              ...state,
              newArr1: [...state.newArr1, item]
            }

           default:
            return state
        }
```

State

```
export const FAVORITES_STATE = {
  newArr1: [],
  newArr2: [],
}
```

I don't see errors or warnings in console or from TypeScript (which I use) but didn't include in the example for simplicity reasons. Also, I would definitely appreciate suggestions on a better structure as I'm not sure that iterating through an array (that can have hundreds or thousands of object) every time is a great idea.

**EDIT**

I think the problem is that each case in the switch inside `map()` doesn't return anything. Logging inside the `map()` function or inside each `case:` I get correct objects and correct ids.

Comment: Your `favReducer` has no `return` statements. They are all in this function `item => {...}`

Comment: Also, for your definition, you pass in arr1 into the functin, but it is a map, so you need to say: `action: arr1`

Comment: @Thomas if you mean the return of the first switch (the one that get the action) there is a return but I haven't included it here. I'll update the example. For the reducer in general (the reducer function) I didn't know I need a return. I mean i never returned anything from the actual reducer before (only iside the switch )

Comment: @Fallenreaper Where exactly do you mean?

Comment: your action creator needs a key>value pair, does it not?  you are implying that categorize_arrays is going to return a map of 2 k->v pairs.  Except it looks like it is not sound as there is no key for *arr1* and looks like you want the key to be *action* as stated above in your codebase

Comment: @Fallenreaper Not sure if I understand correctly but no it doesn't need a key for arr1. Or to be precise there is a key that is called arr1 but it is omitted as also the value is called arr1

Comment: if you are shure that your switch doesn't enter `case 28` even if the id of the item is `28` i would check if the `id` is maybe a string. you can properly do this with `switch (+item.id)`

Comment: @julianlibor check latest edit

Comment: I would also check if i have to change my state before using the reducer. you can do the logic inside the action creator or even befor using them.

Comment: @julianlibor I would like to stay away from that kind of antipatterns (such as putting logic inside action creators) since this is a fairly big app and I don't want to have any strange problems in the future.  But what do you mean with 'check if i have to change my state before using the reducer' ?

Comment: @grenos: i mean that you can do the "what to change" stuff in the reducer - but the "do I want to change something?" outside/before